# session passing to Class File and retrieve by gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, class, datagridview, shopping-cart

i going to create a session and store at class file, when i click a button add to cart. after than display by using a gridview. Anyone can give me a simple concept. i almost giveup to doing this coz i don't know. i going add into database lolz. when i click a button add to cart the code correct? coz i new from asp.net. how to show on gridview?

my class file got error

```
 /*missiong partial modifier on declaration of type'E-commerce_shoppingCart'; 
   another partial declaration of this type exists
public class ShoppingCart
{
    //Consists of a Price (the sum of all of your items)
    public decimal Total { get { return Items.Sum(i => i.Subtotal); } }
    //The total number of items in your cart
    public int TotalItems { get { return Items.Count; } }

    //A Collection of "Cart Items"
    public List<CartItem> Items { get; set; }

    //Basic constructor
    public ShoppingCart()
    {
        Items = new List<CartItem>();
    }
}

//A Shopping Cart Item
public class CartItem
{
    public string ItemID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
    public int Quantity { get; set; }

    //Returns the subtotal (price * quantity)
    public decimal Subtotal { get { return Price * Quantity; } }

    public CartItem()
    {

    }

    //Constructor that accepts your items
    public CartItem(string id, string name, decimal price, int quantity)
    {
        ItemID = id;
        Name = name;
        Price = price;
        Quantity = quantity;
    }
}
```

at my product detail page how should i create a session, and store one by one, because have some contitions

```
if (Session["Cart"] == null)
                {
                    Session["Cart"] = new ShoppingCart();
                }


                ShoppingCart cart = Session["Cart"] as ShoppingCart;


   //below correct? need to put else? how to store one by one           
 cart.Items.Add(new CartItem(Id, lblName.Text, Decimal.Parse(lblPrice.Text), int.Parse(txtAddtoCart.Text)));
//how should i store at class file, my id is passing from query string, assuming now is static


                Session["Cart"] = cart;
```

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: Cart.Item(string id,string name,Decimal price,int quantity) (+1 overload(s))

Error
The best overloaded method match 'E_Commerce.CartItem.CartItem(string, string,decimal,int)' have some invalid arguments

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Judging by the error you're getting, it looks like you need to convert lblPrice.Text to a decimal and txtAddtoCart.Text to an int. Your method is expecting a decimal and an int but you're passing all strings at the moment.

```
Convert.ToDecimal(lblPrice.Text)
Convert.ToInt32(lbltxtAddtoCart.Text)
```

Comment: cart.Items.Add(new CartItem(Id, lblName.Text, Decimal.Parse(lblPrice.Text), int.Parse(txtAddtoCart.Text)));
this correct? how i retrive from from gridview?

Comment: Where is this gridview? What kind of project is this?